# Getting a variable list from a variable

Tags: java, for-loop, yaml, bukkit

I am using the Bukkit 1.8 API. I have made a configuration file to edit the code. I have a list of ranks within the config, which I am looping through with this

```
for(String ranks : plugin.getConfig().getStringList("selllallranks"))
```

The list of ranks within the config looks like this

```
selllallranks:
- 'a'
- 'b'
- 'c'
- 'd'
- 'e'
- 'f'
# etc...
```

Then I head on over to checking the inventory with the blocks to sell at a price, editable within the config. Here is the rest of the code that I have

```
for(String sellallsell : plugin.getConfig().getStringList("sellall" + ranks))
{
    if(p.getInventory().contains(Material.valueOf(sellallsell)))
    {

    }
}
```

I tried looping through it as a string list. The only problem is that I am not looping through a string list, but a variable list. Bukkit API does not have a method for this.
The configuration file would look something like this when editting

```
sellalla:
    cobblestone: 10
    dirt: 1
    diamond_block: 1000
```

Each one of the variables under here would represent the Material name, followed along with the price of it.

What my problem is, is getting these variables within the config as a list. In this list I would want to loop through it and check if it is in the player's inventory. After this I would want to get the amount of each material, and multiply it by the pricing. Then I would add money into the player's account.

The only thing I would need for fixing would be *how* to get the variable list from the sellalla: variable. I would also want to get the integers from this.

Comment: Off-topic: Is Bukkit still going? There's no hard and fast yes/no on the Bukkit website.

Comment: @DanPantry [Spigot](http://www.spigotmc.org/) is still alive.

Comment: @DanPantry Bukkit stopped making newer versions, and all their downloads have been deleted for some legal reason. If you have a jar file of bukkit, you can still use it.

Comment: @JarFile I'm aware it's dead, I was just confused by the use of the API here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the list of keys in a path, you could use:

```
plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("path").getKeys(false);
```

So, for example, if the above code was run on this configuration:

```
path:
    key0: 55
    key1: 72
    key2: 8
```

You would get the `List<String>` containing the values `key0`, `key1`, and `key2`. Then, to get the values for those keys, you could simply use:

```
plugin().getConfig().get("path." + key);
```

`getConfigurationSection(String)` selects the section of the config at arg0 (this method is just used to get an API Object)

`getKeys(false)` gets all of the keys in the above section. Using `false` makes it only get the first keys, and not the next ones. For example, `getKeys(true)` would return `key0`, `subkey0`, `key1`, and `subkey1`, whereas `getKeys(false)` would only return `key0` and `key1`:

```
 path:
     key0:
         subkey0: 10
     key1:
         subkey1: 6
```

So, your code could look something like this:

```
for(String key : plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("sellall")){
    Material material = Material.valueOf(key); //the material
    int value = plugin().getConfig().getInt("sellall." + key); //the sell price of the material

    //the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can can you explain to me what the methods: `getConfigurationSelection` and `getKeys(false)` exactly do?

Comment: `.getConigurationSelection(String)` is not a method, so I changed it to `.getConfigurationSection(String)` and it says I can only iterate over an array or instance. Does that return an array?

Comment: @Jojodmo You wrote *getConfiguration**Selection***. It is *getConfiguration**Section***.

Comment: @Jojodmo I just noticed this for when continuing my code. After I tested it: `int value = plugin().getConfig().getInt("sellall." + key);` is returning to 0, however in my config I have it: `sellalla:
  COBBLESTONE: 10` I have checked this with the server config, and it is the same.

Comment: If you're using `plugin().getConfig().getInt("sellall." + key);`, it won't work if your config has `sellalla: COBBLESTONE: 10`. All the names need to be exact, so you need to make it If you're using `plugin().getConfig().getInt("sellalla." + key);`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `HashMap` ( you can iterate through them using `HashMap.getEntry()` )

Here are a few useful links:

[Read a HashMap from Config](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps)

[Write a HashMap to Config](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps_2)

Comment: I don't exactly get it. Can you explain it better. The links do not make that much sense to me.